# How to pass custom UITableViewCell in a selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that contains a UISwitch and a UILabel. When the switch has been tapped, I would like to know which cell has had their switch activated/deactivated.

I have the following code in my cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod to add the target to my cell's UISwitch:

```
[cell.notifSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChangedFromCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Here is the code for the selector:

```
- (void)switchChangedFromCell:(id)sender {

    HydrationNotificationTableViewCell *cell = (HydrationNotificationTableViewCell *)sender;

    if ([cell.notifSwitch isOn]) {
        NSLog(@"Notification for %@ has been activated", cell.notifLabel.text);
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"Deactivated notification %@", cell.notifLabel.text);
    }
}
```

Right off the bat I believe that it is wrong of me to cast the sender as a cell, since the sender really is the UISwitch from the cell. I would like to know how I can pass the cell itself as well so I know which cell has been changed.

One solution is to set a different tag for each UISwitch in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner solution.

Comment: If you want to get the reference of the UITableViewCell in which you have added the UISwitch you can make use of "testSwitch?.superview as? HydrationNotificationTableViewCell"

Comment: Yes I just posted an answer for this but I think I'm going to go ahead and create a category for UITableView

Comment: Ya @Duncan C's answer is a good choice, And if you want to go with any other option, you can create custom class for UISwitch and add a property of NSIndexPath type in it and in cellForRow:AtIndexPath you can assign the index path to the switch property and on the target you can get the indexPath in such way also, I hope it might also be a good choice.

Comment: That's also another good option. I appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you, Its all based on our personal interest and style of the approach, you can make use of a better choice as you want, but in the end both the solutions would give you the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bad news is that you can't do that... exactly.

The good news is that in your IBAction the `UISwitch` is the sender, and you can use that to figure out which cell contains the `UISwitch`.

I have a project on Github called [TableViewExtension](https://github.com/DuncanMC/TableViewExtension/tree/master/TableViewExtension) that shows how to do it.

The only real trick is this extension to UITableView:

```
public extension UITableView {

  /**
  This method returns the indexPath of the cell that contains the specified view
   - Parameter view: The view to find.
   - Returns: The indexPath of the cell containing the view, or nil if it can't be found
  */

  func indexPathForView(_ view: UIView) -> IndexPath? {
    let origin = view.bounds.origin
    let viewOrigin = self.convert(origin, from: view)
    let indexPath = self.indexPathForRow(at: viewOrigin)
    return indexPath
  }
}
```

If you add that extension you can then make your IBAction use the sender to figure out which control triggered the tap, and call that method to figure out which cell contains that control:

```
@IBAction func controllTriggered(_ sender: UISwitch) {
  guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForView(sender) else { return }

  //Now you have the indexPath of the cell containing `sender`
}
```

### Edit:

Note that in your code you are trying to get the cell, and then query the different subviews of the cell to get state data. Don't do that. You should be storing your state data in your model object. The cell is for displaying information and interacting with the user.

If the user taps a switch the IBAction will have the switch as it's sender parameter. You can get the value of the Switch from sender.

Comment: Ahh this is interesting. As I'm using Objective-C I can create a category on UITableView and convert this swift code. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed that bit. Yes, I had a similar category for Objective-C before I switched to Swift.

Comment: Also you're right - my architecture is off. I will create the model for the cell's name and switchStatus to populate the data instead of the cell state.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only pass the sender in a selector method like that.

You could consider having the UISwitch method be in your custom UITableViewCell class, and create a delegate protocol for your custom class that passes the cell to your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution but this is also a bit ugly. I casted the cell to the sender's superview's superview (UISwitch >> Content View >> Cell)

```
HydrationNotificationTableViewCell *cell = (HydrationNotificationTableViewCell *)([senderSwitch superview].superview);
```

Hopefully there's a cleaner solution out there.